# How to integrate ES6 Module syntax in RequireJS project

Tags: javascript, requirejs, babeljs, amd, es6-modules

I'm looking for a way to use ES6 Modules (import/export) syntax in my current RequireJS project.
I can run my project directly in a recent browser, without build or Babel transformation.
I build my project with r.js and Babel only for production.

We would like to start building ES6 modules and use it with requireJS.
Is there a way to do that ?

NB : RequireJS does not load dependencies written in ES6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, RequireJS should be compatible with Babel's [es2015-modules-umd](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-umd/) plugin. So you should be able to use `import` and `export` in your files during development with a modern browser that supports modules, then use r.js and Babel w/that plugin for production.

Comment: The problem is that RequireJS does not load dependencies written in ES6. Even in a modern browser

Comment: @Acidnuk: By the time RequireJS sees it, it's not in ES6 anymore (at least, not the `import`/`export` part). That's why Babel's involved at that stage, to transform `import`/`export` into `require`/`define` calls.

Comment: Yes it is actually in production. But my application will not work during development, right?

Comment: @Acidnuk: That's why I said *"...with a modern browser that supports modules..."* Recent versions of Chrome do, for instance; I think the latest Safari as well (Safari actually got there first, in their pre-release branch). You bootstrap with `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>` and then `main.js` can use `import { foo } from "./foo.js";` and such. So that's development. Then for test and production you run it through Babel, probably use Require et. al. to build a combined, minified file, et voila.

Comment: Ok, i got it.  Sorry if my initial question was not precise enough. So that means I can not get an es6 module via requireJS. like: 
    `define (["myES6Module.js"], function () {});`

Comment: @Acidnuk: No, the syntaxes are different. To use RequireJS, you have to transpile all of your modules so they use RequireJS syntax.

Comment: Personally, in a client project, I just decided to migrate from Require.js to Browserify (+Gulp). It will require re-writing of the JS code, but the benefits outweigh the challenges (in my opinion).