# How to load requirejs files into creat-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, create-react-app

I am creating a project using create-react-app where my components make use of third party library. That third party library contains javascript files built using require js. When I am tring to use that library in creat-react-app it's throwing the following error :

```
Expected imports instead of AMD define()  import/no-amd
```

Line 1:1:      'define' is not defined

Help me out in using requirejs files in create-react-app.

I also went through this [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3247) but didn't find solution

Comment: A library that still doesn't provide a CJS or ES6 module version is a library you might want to avoid...

Comment: @ThiefMaster I tried it loading webpack but got the following error:FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: @ThiefMaster, can this be helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631520/how-to-integrate-es6-module-syntax-in-requirejs-project)